# sharing the parameters when using tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm building a neural network, which is processing two sets of images in parallel. I want the two columns to share the parameters. This is what I do.

`with tf.variable_scope(layer_name) as s:
    h1 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs = x1, num_outputs = 10, kernel_size = [3, 3], stride = [1, 1], padding = 'VALID', scope = s)
    h2 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs = x2, num_outputs = 10, kernel_size = [3, 3], stride = [1, 1], padding = 'VALID', reuse = True, scope = s)`

Is this the correct way to do this? I can't find an example of how to do that correctly when using tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't correct make it into a function like so:

```
def function(x, reuse):
  with tf.variable_scope(layer_name) as s:
    output = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs = x, num_outputs = 10, kernel_size = [3, 3], 
                   stride = [1, 1], padding = 'VALID', reuse = reuse, scope = s)
    return output

output1 = function(image1, False)
output2 = function(image2, True)
```

Now when it's called with different inputs the same weights will be reused.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I meant the inputs to be different (corrected above). I would think however that if I executed your code, it wouldn't work. I thought the the 'reuse' flag can be set to True only if the variables have been created earlier. Am I wrong?

Comment: My inputs are different image1 does not equal image2. Also you're statement is incorrect. The contrib layers creates the variables for you.  You are merely specifying that if called again in the same computation graph I want them to be reused.

Comment: There is something I don't seem to understand about your answer. If I do, which should be the same as you suggest (except a wrapper function, I deleted some parameters to fit in the character limit):

with tf.variable_scope("conv1") as s:
    h1 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs = x1, reuse = True, scope = s)
    h2 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs = x2, reuse = True, scope = s)

I'm getting an error at h1:
ValueError: Variable conv1/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, I don't seem to be able to add an enter in the comment.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it can reflect the fact that layers.convolution2d will force to reuse a variable if reuse = True.  I think this is a bug personally but tensorflow tries to make these things explicit.

Comment: So what I wrote in the question (after editing it, like it is now) is correct, right? I think it's the same as your answer except for the wrapper function. Or is setting reuse to False different than not setting it at all?

Comment: Yes it should be correct now. That you updated your question but now it's not really a question anymore.